# Add interface that is up to a bridge

Tags: networking, network-interface, bridge

I'm trying to compose `/etc/network/interfaces` that would combine two ethernet interfaces in a brdige. The problem is that the system boots using PXE loader and NFS root, and one of the interfaces already gets its IP during the NFS mount stage. It's probably fine to add an interface with assigned IP to a bridge, but for some reason my `/etc/network/interfaces` setup fails. It looks something like:

```
# initrd assigns IP to eth0 automatically
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
post-down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up
post-down ifconfig $IFACE down

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

I believe that before `br0` can be brought up, `eth0` should be brought down and assigned something like `0.0.0.0`.

Is there an automated way to tell networking tools that I would like to disregard any setup that either `eth0` or `eth1` already has, and setup `br0` from those two?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your NFS-root setup? If this is setup in the initramfs, I'd just setup the bridge in the initramfs also, so it's correct in the first place *before* the NFS-root happens. Doing a bridge later (and even reacquiring IP through DHCP) doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Yes, the NFS mounts happens within initramfs. Making a bridge there is my fallback solution, but in order to do that I would have to include bridge making program (bridge-utils) and who knows what else. So I was looking for an easier solution. Why do you think though it's a bad idea to make a bridge after initramfs?

Comment: the only needed command to handle a basic bridge is iproute2's `ip` command. about the bad idea: as soon as you lose network connectivity your next script's command which would restore it can fail because it's not executable anymore: NFS isn't working anymore